# Return value type is not correct for JavaScript expression in Java due to XOR bitwise ^ operator

Tags: java, javascript, bit-manipulation, xor, scriptengine

I'm trying to evaluate this expression:

```
ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager () 
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = sem.getEngineByName("js") ;
String expr = "true ^ true";
Boolean obj = (Boolean) scriptEngine.eval(expr);
```

However the result returned is java Double.  I have tried various option for String expr such as:

`String expr = "0x1 ^ 0x0";` 
`String expr = "1 ^ 0";`

Basically I want to be able to use JavaScript engine to evaluate various expressions which may look like this:

```
"ture && false || false (true || false && true || false XOR true)"
```

All the other operators like && or || work just fine when I evaluate such expressions and return Boolean but when it comes XOR (which has JavaScript equivalent bitwise ^ operator) it returns Double.  I don't really want to convert the expression to replace XOR to some logical operators (e.g. ((true || false) && !(true && false)) ) because then I'd have to parse the whole expression string to convert XOR into above logical expression.  The whole point of my evaluating this expression is so that I am able to evaluate without having to parse its complexity.

Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the original expression should read: String expr = "true ^ true";

Comment: Just edit your question. There's an `edit` link at the bottom. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from here: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/xor.html

"Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have a logical XOR operator. It has a bitwise XOR operator ^ that can perform a bitwise comparison of two numbers, but this does not help when you want to obtain the result of an XOR of two expressions, that do not return a number.

The XOR operator can be simulated using this:

```
if( ( foo && !bar ) || ( !foo && bar ) ) {
  ...
}
```

Or with one less operation (depending on the values of the foo and bar) using this:

```
if( ( foo || bar ) && !( foo && bar ) ) {
  ...
}
```

Or using the ternary operator to make it even smaller:

```
if( foo ? !bar : bar ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It can also be simulated for booleans with `!=`

Comment: Diego, thanks but like I mentioned it won't solve my problem.

Comment: Then why are you using the JavaScript engine? Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203003/boolean-expression-parser-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You could force a cast to boolean in the JavaScript code using a double negation:

```
Boolean obj = (Boolean) scriptEngine.eval("!!(" + expr + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using XOR, it is more natural to write `!=`  e.g. `true != false`  I would be surprised if this didn't work in Javascript.

Comment: @archer Javascript doesn't have an XOR so you have translate it to something javascript does have.

Comment: I don't know JS very well but getting a double from a bitwise operation is a bit insane. ;)

Comment: seems JS turns boolean to Number before doing bitwise XOR this is why it returns Double.

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing this solution in absence of any clear alternative:

```
    boolean useDouble = false;
    String expr = "true ^ false";
    if(expr.contains("^"))
    {
        useDouble = true;
    }
            ...
            if(useDouble)
         {
             Double d = (Double) scriptEngine.eval(expr); 
             boolean r = (d != 0.0);
             System.out.println(" result: " + r);
         }
         else
         {
             Boolean b = (Boolean)scriptEngine.equals(expr);
             System.out.println(b.getClass().getName() + "result:" + b);
         }
```