# Parse parenthesized Boolean String Expressions with Java

Tags: java, string, parsing, evaluation, boolean-expression

I need to evaluate a parenthesized boolean expression I receive in a String. Since I need to deal with variable expression i need to find a way to parse it into a boolean expression to evaluate it in java. An example for an String expression is:

```
String boolexpr1 = "(!(true||false)&&!((true)^(true)))"
```

The possible operators are parentheses, AND,  OR, XOR, NOT. Since this is already a Java-processable expression I thought it should be easy to parse it, but couldn't think of a elegant solution. I also found some code online, but it either deals with other/less operators, without parentheses or is still too complex.

Comment: Did you tried applying regex and convert them to Boolean?

Comment: I think this is a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203003/boolean-expression-parser-in-java

Comment: Are you looking for parsing or just want final result?

Comment: The final result will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using JavaScript:

```
String boolexpr1 = "(!(true||false)&&!((true)^(true)))"
boolean result = (Boolean) new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("javascript").eval(boolexpr1);
```

Didn't expect it could be that simple.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Spring you can use the [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html), which supports the same boolean expression like this and:

- it's typically *way* faster (in my rough tests, it's 20-22 times faster) than the JS engine;
- the parser instance is thread safe;
- it's simple to use, just like the JS engine;
- it's far less resources intensive than the JS engine (in production, the CPU usage jumped from 5% to 60% with the JS engine. It remained the same with SpEL).

Example of usage:

```
ExpressionParser ep = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = ep.parseExpression("(!(true||false)&&!((true) != (true)))");
exp.getValue(Boolean.class);
```

The XOR operator (`^`) for booleans works exactly like the Not Equal operator (`!=`), so you can map it to that.