# Evaluating boolean expressions in Java dynamically

Tags: java, boolean-expression, evaluate

I made use of JEP earlier and then realised that it wont fit my case.

On a call to the database/backend, I get a json response, which has a structure as below:

```
"key": {
"!A & B"
}
```

And there will be values for A and B like true or false.

I used bpodgursky.jbool_expressions, but do not understand how to substitute values:

```
 Expression<String> parsedExpression = RuleSet.simplify(ExprParser.parse("!A&B"));
    RuleSet.assign("A", Boolean.TRUE); //THIS IS WRONG
```

Could anybody help me with the correct library to work on and some sample example to do so?

Comment: Maybe this post is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203003/boolean-expression-parser-in-java

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/bpodgursky/jbool_expressions), you're supposed to pass the expression and a map to `RuleSet.assign`. See under "**Variable Assignment**". Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create it like this.

```
Expression<String> expression = RuleSet.simplify(ExprParser.parse("!A&B"));
Map<String, Object> keyValue = Map.of("A", false, "B", true);
Expression<String> resolved = RuleSet.assign(expression, keyValue);
System.out.println(resolved); // returns true
```

Refer this documentation for more clarity on how to use it: https://github.com/bpodgursky/jbool_expressions